# Why the pods running with a service account with needed permissions cannot list pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, rbac

I have created a service account "serviceacc" in a namespace xyz and gave it needed permissions. Yet it could not list pods. Here are the steps I followed.

```
$kubectl create namespace xyz

$kubectl apply -f objects.yaml
```

Where content of objects.yaml

```
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: xyz
  name: listpodser
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pod"]
    verbs: ["get", "list"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: xyz
  name: service-listpodser
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: serviceacc 
    apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: listpodser
  apiGroup: ""

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: serviceacc
  namespace: xyz
```

Then I checked if the service account has permission to list pods:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --namespace  xyz --as system:serviceaccount:xyz:serviceacc
no

$ kubectl auth can-i list pods --namespace  xyz --as system:serviceaccount:xyz:serviceacc
no
```

As we can see from the output of above command, it cannot get/list pods.

Comment: Just a thought. Does it make any difference if you have `pods` (plural) instead of `pod` in the resource list?

Comment: @JulioHM You are right. That made it work. I was working with it for long time, pulling my hairs and was not going anywhere :). It worked now. Thanks a lot.  Add your comment as answer. I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple naming confusion. Use `pods` instead of `pod` in the resource list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simpler and easier this way:

```sh
kubectl create sa serviceacc -n xyz
kubectl create role listpodser --verb=get,list --resource=po -n xyz
kubectl create -n xyz rolebinding service-listpodser --role=listpodser --serviceaccount=xyz:serviceacc
```

> **Note** the short name for pods is accepted here `po`, you can use the short name for any api object

> **short names**: If you need to list the short names for all objects, run this command `kubectl apu-resources`, the same way you can use the short name for other objects.*e.g. pv instead of persistentvolume.*

This way you can write these three lines into a shell script to create all in one shot

Comment: most welcome :)